# firebase otp showing error that the number is not valid formate e1.64

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, one-time-password

i am trying to genrate otp with firebase when am trying italian number for otp genrate showing this below message please let me know i am very thank full if any any kind of help
thanks

[image]

Comment: Please add a Minimal Reproducible Example. You can find the details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: please log the number you have given to the firebase and add it to the question.

Answer (score 0):

This happens when you have an invalid number that was passed to the firebase SDK. I can only help if you give the number that was passed to the SDK.

However, use the following format in the number:

> **Format**: +[country code][number]

Also remove any spaces in the number using:

> number.replace(" ", "")